# Need help on event and observer in magento 1.9.x.x checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I need to listen to the events in the checkout onepage with an observer. The goal is to count the number of times that a command is passed by a user and at the end of the tenth command, I offer him/her a gift.

So this is my config.xml with event

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <observe_order_pour_mails>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mymodule_custom/observer</class>
                    <method>countOrder</method>
                </observe_order_pour_mails>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

and this is my observer

```
<?php 

 class Mymodule_Custom_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer {


 public function __construct() {}

/**
 * @param $observer
 */
public function countOrder($observer) {

    //$from_date = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime(2016-9-11));
    //$to_date = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime(2017-9-13));

    $customer_groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();

    $ii = 0 ; // init counter 
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds(); // get event of orderIds

    Mage::log(count($order), null, 'order.log'); // count order , always equals 1 in log 

    if(count($order) > 0 ){ 

        $ii++; // counter

        Mage::log( $ii, null, 'counter.log');

        if ($ii = 10){ // if counter of order = 2 , one customer win

             Mage::log('win', null, 'win.log');
             $ii = 0 ; // réinit counter when order = 2 
        }   

    }
 }
```

I need that at the end of the command, the user wins and receives an email to warn him/her that he/she has won. I would like that once this is done, the count will reset to zero and that another user can also win for a given period.

Thank you for helping me because I am a little lost

Comment: Which type of command?

Comment: When status of command is processing

Comment: where you store command status? and where to use that command?

Comment: explain more on command

Comment: In fact, when a customer validates his order and payment is ok, the customer is redirecting to the sucess page, I want to count the number of orders that are ok and at the 10th command give a gift to my customer. For this I use the observe in checkout_onepage_controller_success_action. how do I count the number of events up to 10

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function countOrder($observer) {

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());
$_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$order->getCustomerId());                        
$_orderCnt = $_orders->count();

//stuff here 

 }
```

This may help you.